# get data from ar_pose_marker with quick camera moves

Tags: camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm trying to read with ar-track-alvar, the data of a camera mounted on a vehicle and with the vibrations due to movement, I almost do not get results in the topic ar_pose_marker. The stopped vehicle reads perfectly.
Are there solutions for this?
Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280404/get-data-from-ar_pose_marker-with-quick-camera-moves/) by [mag.rod](https://answers.ros.org/users/30299/mag.rod/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2018-01-21

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MatthijsBurgh](https://answers.ros.org/users/33371/matthijsburgh/) on 2018-01-21**:
Start with checking the camera topic. Does the publish rate drop, when vibrations are taking place?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2018-01-21**:
Are you using a global shutter or rolling shutter camera? With a rolling shutter, the vibration in your vehicle could introduce significant distortion into the camera image that may make it unusable for tradition computer vision techniques.

**Comment by [mag.rod](https://answers.ros.org/users/30299/mag.rod/) on 2018-01-22**:
Is a usb logitec camera

**Comment by [mag.rod](https://answers.ros.org/users/30299/mag.rod/) on 2018-01-22**:
When it vibrates it keeps publishing but as if it did not see the code ar

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2018-01-23**:
You may want to look at the captured images when your robot is stationary and when it is moving to make sure that the images are not distorted. If you'd like more help please capture these images and add them to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is almost certainly a problem caused by a reduction in the quality of images from the camera. If you save a few examples of images captured when the vehicle is static and moving then you will probably see a big difference. By the sounds of it you're using a basic webcam which won't be helping.

Vibrations can cause all sorts of camera image problems from shear on rolling shutter cameras, motion blur, focus bleeds and more. You may be able to solve these problems by making your camera mounting more physically robust and or getting a higher quality camera. Action cameras such as GoPros are a good choice in this situation because they're designed to work in these sorts of environments.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1